# unable to append using if statement

Tags: python, list, if-statement, append

I have three lists. I would like to append the list object onto the 'filtered' list if the object contains "HP" or "LP." The output places all items of filenames onto 'filtered' instead. Unsure why this is occurring. Your insight would be appreciated!

```
filenames = ['HP PLEAS 56s Jazz.wav', 'HP PLEAS 57s groupLaughing.wav', 'HP 
PLEAS 57s Guitar_2.wav', 'PLEAS 56s Jazz.wav']
filtered = []
original = []

for x in filenames:
    if "LP" or "HP" in x:
        filtered.append(x)
    else:
        original.append(x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the condition  `"LP" or "HP" in x` is always `True`, equivalent to your condition : `("LP") or ("HP" in x)`, where `("LP")` is alway `True`, you can use:

```
for x in filenames:
    if ("LP" in x) or ("HP" in x):
        filtered.append(x)
    else:
        original.append(x)
```

Comment: Hello Kederrac. Thank you so much for the answer. Could you tell me a bit as to why the two codes are functioning different?